# Join two tables by columnname when columnames for joining stored in a table

Tags: list, join, pyspark

i try to join two tables by a list which was created from an other table.
But i didn't find a way how it works.

Base would be:

```
data = [('B_YEAR, B_ORG', 'YEAR, ORG', 1), ('B_YEAR', 'YEAR', 2) ]
test = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['key_orig', 'key_map', 'Fil_Number']) 
fc_year == 2024
```

Now i try to join:

```
for i in range (1,x):
test_1= test.filter(col("Fil_Number")==1)
list_key_orig = test_1.select("key_orig").collect()
list_key_map = test_1.select("key_map").collect()

df_calc_values =spark.read.table("hive_metastore.reporting_datalake.df_calc_fc_values")

df_calc_values = df_calc_values.filter((col("GJ")==fc_year))
display(df_calc_values)

df_new= df_orig.join(df_calc_values, on = (key_orig1.key_orig == key_map1.key_map) ,how = "left")
```

I already searched in google but no result.

Tables:

**Table - df_calc_values**
[image]

**Table - df_orig**
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all your question is a disaster! There are no insights where the original DataFrame came from. Also your for loop is not correct indented. So it is not feasible to recognize what is part of your loop and what not. your `fc_year` variable is not declared. You are importing all namespacing from the functions module of pyspark by `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` that you should absolutely not do to avoid naming conflicts and stuff like that in your code. Also you cannot expect an answer if a question plucked out of air and without any relations to each other.

Anyway I tried to provide you an answer on how you can build a joining string out of your given information and how to join two DataFrames by this string.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df_calc_values =spark.read.table("hive_metastore.reporting_datalake.df_calc_fc_values")
df_orig = spark.read.table("original_table from wherever the table came from")
max_fil_no = test.agg(f.max("Fil_Number").alias("max")).first().max
fc_year = 2024
alias_original = "original"
alias_calc_val = "calc_vals"

dfs = {}

for i in range(1, max_fil_no+1):
    test_1= test.filter(f.col("Fil_Number")==i)
    list_key_orig = test_1.select("key_orig").collect()
    list_key_map = test_1.select("key_map").collect()

    join_cols_original = [x.replace(" ", "") for x in list_key_orig[0].key_orig.split(",")]
    join_cols_calc_vals = [x.replace(" ", "") for x in list_key_map[0].key_map.split(",")]
    
    join_str_combos = []
    for key_orig, key_cal_vals in zip(join_cols_original, join_cols_calc_vals):
        join_str_combos.append(f"{alias_original}.{key_orig} == {alias_calc_val}.{key_cal_vals}")

    join_str = " AND ".join(join_str_combos)

    df_calc_values = df_calc_values.filter((f.col("GJ")==fc_year))

    df_new = (
        df_orig.alias(alias_original)
        .join(
            df_calc_values.alias(alias_calc_val),
            on=f.expr(join_str),
            how="left"
        )
    )
    dfs[i] = df_new
```

Comment: Hello Samuel,

thank you for the post.
You are right, the format is not so good, sorry for that, I am not so sure with stackoverflow.

When I transfer it to my real data, I get an error in the last step:


`USING column orig.B_YEAR== calc.YEAR AND orig.B_ORG== calc.ORG cannot be resolved on the left side of the join`

But the columns are present in both tables.

Comment: I don’t see your code and your dataframe. It sound like the column is not there..

Comment: I have added the tables in the first post

Comment: Problem is that "join_str" is a string and the "on=" can't use it as string. When i copy the join string direct it works

Comment: Sry but you are definitely wrong. The „on“ argument can have a string as input. See the pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join operation.